# How to assign private IP in multiple EC2 instance?

Tags: terraform

I want to assign 10 private IP (already selected) to 10 different type of EC2 instance spread across different AZ, pls help.

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your short question and on the tag saying "terraform", I think that you are looking for what is explained in the doc here https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance.

To set up an ec2 instance with some IPs you choose, you should create before an *aws_network_interface* that will be attached to it (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/network_interface).

Double-check that all the IPs you want are under the same *aws_subnet* (which is another terraform resource to be defined first)

EDIT

Let me try to add an example (i can't test it at the moment but it should be easily verified)

EXAMPLE:

I'll pick the values from the doc, and we assume that 3 IPs you have already chosen are 172.16.10.100, 172.16.10.101, 172.16.10.102. All of them are included in the subnet range.

```
resource "aws_vpc" "my_vpc" {
  cidr_block = "172.16.0.0/16"

  tags = {
    Name = "tf-example"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "my_subnet" {
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id
  cidr_block        = "172.16.10.0/24"
  availability_zone = "us-west-2a"

  tags = {
    Name = "tf-example"
  }
}

resource "aws_network_interface" "foo" {
  subnet_id   = aws_subnet.my_subnet.id
  private_ips = ["172.16.10.100", "172.16.10.101", "172.16.10.102"]

  tags = {
    Name = "primary_network_interface"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "foo" {
  ami           = "ami-005e54dee72cc1d00" # us-west-2
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  network_interface {
    network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.foo.id
    device_index         = 0
  }

  credit_specification {
    cpu_credits = "unlimited"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "foo_first" {
  ami           = "ami-005e54dee72cc1d00" # us-west-2
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  network_interface {
    network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.foo.id
    device_index         = 1
  }

  credit_specification {
    cpu_credits = "unlimited"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "foo_second" {
  ami           = "ami-005e54dee72cc1d00" # us-west-2
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  network_interface {
    network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.foo.id
    device_index         = 2
  }

  credit_specification {
    cpu_credits = "unlimited"
  }
}
```

Comment: I know about this doc. Could you please give me an example?